# Does Travis-CI require SQLite setup for PHP project?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, travis-ci

I just started to use Travis CI, after several attempts, I have a passing build (hoora) using MySQL.
But SQLite build is still failing on the first `PDO->prepare` command (I suppose that because the next line is about `PDO->execute` and log says that my object is a boolean instead of PDO object...).

Here is the code:

```
$query = $connection->prepare('UPDATE `user` SET `password`=:password WHERE `id`=1 LIMIT 1;');
$query->bindValue(':password', md5($adminUserPwd), PDO::PARAM_STR);
if (!$query->execute()) { 
    return false;
}
```

Here is the build (PHPUnit) log:

```
Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in /home/travis/build/nioc/web-music-player/tests/TestingTool.php:96
```

Before that step, my script create a SQLite file :

```
//drop previous schema
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path)) {
    unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path);
}
//create directory if it does not already exist
if (!file_exists(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path))) {
    mkdir(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path), 0700);
}
```

And then load a script for tables creations.

Here is the link to the SQLite build : https://travis-ci.org/nioc/web-music-player/jobs/157457638#L190

On local, all tests are ok, I'm wondering why Travis build failed, maybe I forget something on Travis configuration?

Any advice is welcome :)

Comment: I give a new try by adding SQLite directory on the git clone and this on my travis.yml:

`- chmod -R 777 tests/server/data/`

But it still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my issue, SQL request was:

```
UPDATE `user` SET `password`=:password WHERE `id`=1 LIMIT 1;
```

As mentioned in [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit), SQLite does not allow the `LIMIT` clause on UPDATE except if it was compiled with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` option.